# Change Sort Order Based on Filter Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I'm trying to create a dropdown with filtering with US States. The dropdown and filtering work great, but the filtering sorts by first item that contains a value instead of first character, for example:

user types '**Wa**'
first option is "Dela**wa**re"

I want "Washington" to appear first, since a user wouldn't be typing WA for Delaware anyway. How do I go about doing that?

[An example here shows what I mean](https://codepen.io/moustafaishak/pen/bWGZRo)

```
// Events
$('.dropdown-container')
    .on('click', '.dropdown-button', function() {
        $('.dropdown-list').toggle();
    })
    .on('input', '.dropdown-search', function() {
        var target = $(this);
        var search = target.val().toLowerCase();

        if (!search) {
            $('li').show();
            return false;
        }

        $('li').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var match = text.indexOf(search) > -1;
            $(this).toggle(match);
        });
    })
    .on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', function() {
        var numChecked = $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        $('.quantity').text(numChecked || 'Any');
    });

// JSON of States for demo purposes
var usStates = [
    { name: 'ALABAMA', abbreviation: 'AL'},
    { name: 'ALASKA', abbreviation: 'AK'},
    { name: 'AMERICAN SAMOA', abbreviation: 'AS'},
    { name: 'ARIZONA', abbreviation: 'AZ'},
    { name: 'ARKANSAS', abbreviation: 'AR'},
    { name: 'CALIFORNIA', abbreviation: 'CA'},
    { name: 'COLORADO', abbreviation: 'CO'},
    { name: 'CONNECTICUT', abbreviation: 'CT'},
    { name: 'DELAWARE', abbreviation: 'DE'},
    { name: 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA', abbreviation: 'DC'},
    { name: 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA', abbreviation: 'FM'},
    { name: 'FLORIDA', abbreviation: 'FL'},
    { name: 'GEORGIA', abbreviation: 'GA'},
    { name: 'GUAM', abbreviation: 'GU'},
    { name: 'HAWAII', abbreviation: 'HI'},
    { name: 'IDAHO', abbreviation: 'ID'},
    { name: 'ILLINOIS', abbreviation: 'IL'},
    { name: 'INDIANA', abbreviation: 'IN'},
    { name: 'IOWA', abbreviation: 'IA'},
    { name: 'KANSAS', abbreviation: 'KS'},
    { name: 'KENTUCKY', abbreviation: 'KY'},
    { name: 'LOUISIANA', abbreviation: 'LA'},
    { name: 'MAINE', abbreviation: 'ME'},
    { name: 'MARSHALL ISLANDS', abbreviation: 'MH'},
    { name: 'MARYLAND', abbreviation: 'MD'},
    { name: 'MASSACHUSETTS', abbreviation: 'MA'},
    { name: 'MICHIGAN', abbreviation: 'MI'},
    { name: 'MINNESOTA', abbreviation: 'MN'},
    { name: 'MISSISSIPPI', abbreviation: 'MS'},
    { name: 'MISSOURI', abbreviation: 'MO'},
    { name: 'MONTANA', abbreviation: 'MT'},
    { name: 'NEBRASKA', abbreviation: 'NE'},
    { name: 'NEVADA', abbreviation: 'NV'},
    { name: 'NEW HAMPSHIRE', abbreviation: 'NH'},
    { name: 'NEW JERSEY', abbreviation: 'NJ'},
    { name: 'NEW MEXICO', abbreviation: 'NM'},
    { name: 'NEW YORK', abbreviation: 'NY'},
    { name: 'NORTH CAROLINA', abbreviation: 'NC'},
    { name: 'NORTH DAKOTA', abbreviation: 'ND'},
    { name: 'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS', abbreviation: 'MP'},
    { name: 'OHIO', abbreviation: 'OH'},
    { name: 'OKLAHOMA', abbreviation: 'OK'},
    { name: 'OREGON', abbreviation: 'OR'},
    { name: 'PALAU', abbreviation: 'PW'},
    { name: 'PENNSYLVANIA', abbreviation: 'PA'},
    { name: 'PUERTO RICO', abbreviation: 'PR'},
    { name: 'RHODE ISLAND', abbreviation: 'RI'},
    { name: 'SOUTH CAROLINA', abbreviation: 'SC'},
    { name: 'SOUTH DAKOTA', abbreviation: 'SD'},
    { name: 'TENNESSEE', abbreviation: 'TN'},
    { name: 'TEXAS', abbreviation: 'TX'},
    { name: 'UTAH', abbreviation: 'UT'},
    { name: 'VERMONT', abbreviation: 'VT'},
    { name: 'VIRGIN ISLANDS', abbreviation: 'VI'},
    { name: 'VIRGINIA', abbreviation: 'VA'},
    { name: 'WASHINGTON', abbreviation: 'WA'},
    { name: 'WEST VIRGINIA', abbreviation: 'WV'},
    { name: 'WISCONSIN', abbreviation: 'WI'},
    { name: 'WYOMING', abbreviation: 'WY' }
];

// <li> template
var stateTemplate = _.template(
    '<li>' +
        '<input name="<%= abbreviation %>" type="checkbox">' +
        '<label for="<%= abbreviation %>"><%= capName %></label>' +
    '</li>'
);

// Populate list with states
_.each(usStates, function(s) {
    s.capName = _.startCase(s.name.toLowerCase());
    $('ul').append(stateTemplate(s));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some good old vanilla js will let you do this using `filter` and `sort`. This assumes you're okay with the sort order being based on the first matching index in the string:

```
let search = 'WA';

let filtered = usStates
  .filter(state => state.name.includes(search))
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.indexOf(search) - b.name.indexOf(search));

console.log(filtered);
```

And see below to see it in action.

```js
var usStates = [
    { name: 'ALABAMA', abbreviation: 'AL'},
    { name: 'ALASKA', abbreviation: 'AK'},
    { name: 'AMERICAN SAMOA', abbreviation: 'AS'},
    { name: 'ARIZONA', abbreviation: 'AZ'},
    { name: 'ARKANSAS', abbreviation: 'AR'},
    { name: 'CALIFORNIA', abbreviation: 'CA'},
    { name: 'COLORADO', abbreviation: 'CO'},
    { name: 'CONNECTICUT', abbreviation: 'CT'},
    { name: 'DELAWARE', abbreviation: 'DE'},
    { name: 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA', abbreviation: 'DC'},
    { name: 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA', abbreviation: 'FM'},
    { name: 'FLORIDA', abbreviation: 'FL'},
    { name: 'GEORGIA', abbreviation: 'GA'},
    { name: 'GUAM', abbreviation: 'GU'},
    { name: 'HAWAII', abbreviation: 'HI'},
    { name: 'IDAHO', abbreviation: 'ID'},
    { name: 'ILLINOIS', abbreviation: 'IL'},
    { name: 'INDIANA', abbreviation: 'IN'},
    { name: 'IOWA', abbreviation: 'IA'},
    { name: 'KANSAS', abbreviation: 'KS'},
    { name: 'KENTUCKY', abbreviation: 'KY'},
    { name: 'LOUISIANA', abbreviation: 'LA'},
    { name: 'MAINE', abbreviation: 'ME'},
    { name: 'MARSHALL ISLANDS', abbreviation: 'MH'},
    { name: 'MARYLAND', abbreviation: 'MD'},
    { name: 'MASSACHUSETTS', abbreviation: 'MA'},
    { name: 'MICHIGAN', abbreviation: 'MI'},
    { name: 'MINNESOTA', abbreviation: 'MN'},
    { name: 'MISSISSIPPI', abbreviation: 'MS'},
    { name: 'MISSOURI', abbreviation: 'MO'},
    { name: 'MONTANA', abbreviation: 'MT'},
    { name: 'NEBRASKA', abbreviation: 'NE'},
    { name: 'NEVADA', abbreviation: 'NV'},
    { name: 'NEW HAMPSHIRE', abbreviation: 'NH'},
    { name: 'NEW JERSEY', abbreviation: 'NJ'},
    { name: 'NEW MEXICO', abbreviation: 'NM'},
    { name: 'NEW YORK', abbreviation: 'NY'},
    { name: 'NORTH CAROLINA', abbreviation: 'NC'},
    { name: 'NORTH DAKOTA', abbreviation: 'ND'},
    { name: 'NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS', abbreviation: 'MP'},
    { name: 'OHIO', abbreviation: 'OH'},
    { name: 'OKLAHOMA', abbreviation: 'OK'},
    { name: 'OREGON', abbreviation: 'OR'},
    { name: 'PALAU', abbreviation: 'PW'},
    { name: 'PENNSYLVANIA', abbreviation: 'PA'},
    { name: 'PUERTO RICO', abbreviation: 'PR'},
    { name: 'RHODE ISLAND', abbreviation: 'RI'},
    { name: 'SOUTH CAROLINA', abbreviation: 'SC'},
    { name: 'SOUTH DAKOTA', abbreviation: 'SD'},
    { name: 'TENNESSEE', abbreviation: 'TN'},
    { name: 'TEXAS', abbreviation: 'TX'},
    { name: 'UTAH', abbreviation: 'UT'},
    { name: 'VERMONT', abbreviation: 'VT'},
    { name: 'VIRGIN ISLANDS', abbreviation: 'VI'},
    { name: 'VIRGINIA', abbreviation: 'VA'},
    { name: 'WASHINGTON', abbreviation: 'WA'},
    { name: 'WEST VIRGINIA', abbreviation: 'WV'},
    { name: 'WISCONSIN', abbreviation: 'WI'},
    { name: 'WYOMING', abbreviation: 'WY' }
];

let search = 'WA';

let filtered = usStates
  .filter(state => state.name.includes(search))
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.indexOf(search) - b.name.indexOf(search));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Great one-line, vanilla solution. As long as the OP can use ES6 arrow functions, this seems perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6, you can replace:

```
var match = text.indexOf(search) > -1;
```

with

```
var match = text.startsWith(search);
```

Otherwise, you can use a regular expression:

```
var match new RegExp(`^${search}`).test(text)
```